# Django use URL tag in template from app specific urls?

Tags: python, django, url

I have the following URLs in my project `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^register/', include('register.urls')),
)
```

So I maintain urls in the register app, so the `urls.py` in my `register` app looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^test/$', views.Test, name="register_test"),
)
```

So I have a template that is located outside the register app, is located in the root of the project, and I am trying to use the above url like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'register_test' %}"/>Test</a>
```

But I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /en/
Reverse for 'register_test' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried: `<a href="{% url 'register:register_test' %}"/>Test</a>`? 
You might want to give the register urls a name space first though:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^register/', include('register.urls', namespace='register'),
)
```

urls.py in register app:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'register.views',
    url(r'^test/$', 'Test', name="register_test"),
)
```

Django doc about [url namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces).

Comment: Sound like a good point but I get the following error: `TypeError: url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespace'`

Comment: Sorry the brackets are messed up, fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I saw Anjaneyulu answer's and I understood the small typo. I still get the same error though even with this more logical approach. This is strange, because I am on Django 1.9 and URL Namespace is supported in 1.9.

Comment: @John You were missing the first argument to `patterns()`, which is a prefix to the import path of the view. Note that `patterns()` is deprecated in 1.9. The recommended approach is to use a list and import the view: `urlpatterns = [url(r'^test/$', views.Test, name="register_test")]`

Answer (score 0):

project urls.py

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^register/', include('register.urls', namespace="register")),
)
```

app urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^test/$', views.Test, name="register_test"),
)
```

template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'register:register_test' %}"/>Test</a>
```

Comment: For some strange reason I get the same error message